# nginx: block directory but allow access to subdirectory

Tags: nginx, proxy, webserver

I am trying to figure out how I can block a particular directory with nginx, while allowing the resources (including any subdirectories) from that directory to be accessible.  For example,

`/static` should be blocked, however
`/static/whatever.css` should be accessible.

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
    location ^~ /static/ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    location ^~ /static/* {
        allow all;
    }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

That is incorrect syntax. You probably meant to write:

```
location = /static/ {
    deny all;
}

location /static/ {
}
```

The `return 404` is redundant as the `deny all` will return 403. The `allow all` is redundant as it is the default action. I have remove the `^~` modifier, which should be added to prevent the `location` being overridden by any potential regex location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for location syntax.

However, it seems that the only URI you want to deny is the directory itself, perhaps to disable an inherited `index` directive. This may also work (with or without the `^~` modifier - see above):

```
location /static/ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

By omitting the `$uri/` element (note trailing `/`) from the `try_files` directive, the `index` directive is ignored. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I tried the example you provided (both `$uri` and `$uri/`), but I got a `404` error back on `/static/whatever.css`.  Your assumption is correct that I only want to deny access to the directory itself, while allowing access to all subdirectories or resources.

Comment: @cookandy You probably need to show more or your configuration. The 404 response could be caused by a misconfigured `root` or a conflicting `location` block.